# Accessing "Background" attribute in XAML from VB

Tags: vb.net, xaml

im quite new in vb programming..

i have this code snippet in my Form.xaml

```
<MenuItem Name="testItem" Background="Gray" Width="37" >
    <MenuItem.Icon>
        <Image Source="Image\test.png"  Width="35" Height="35"/>
    </MenuItem.Icon>
</MenuItem>
```

and in my Form.xaml.vb how do I access testItem's Background? I did something like

```
testItem.Background = Colors.Blue
```

but it doesnt work..

Comment: When you say "it doesn't work", what do you mean? Did you get a compiler error (and if so, what was it)? No error but it doesn't do what you expect (and if so, what did you expect, and what did it do instead)?

Comment: it says value type of system.drawing.color cannot be converted to system.windows.media.brush

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Background property of the Menu expects a Brush, not a Color. You could use a SolidColorBrush like this:

```
testItem.Background = New SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red)
```

Comment: its still the same, it says value type of system.drawing.color cannot be converted to system.windows.media.brush